# Determine total Delta rotation of iPhone

Tags: ios, rotation, core-motion

I've been trying to break into an understanding of Core Motion, and it feels like I'm failing.

I'm not an engineer, nor a mathematician, so rotational matrices and Euler angles, etc. are (as of yet) a difficult concept for me to wrap my head around.

I'm trying to write an app that can calculate the angle of rotation for an iPhone. Basically, I'm trying to measure range of motion for, say, someone's elbow.

I've gotten a few different test projects working, and it seems like the correct way to go is using `CMAttitude` instances from the `Core Motion` framework.

I've even gotten so far as to (sort of) understand taking a reference frame when I begin asking for motion data, and using `multipleByInverseOfAttitude:` to determine the net change in attitude (did I state that correctly?).

What I don't understand is what to ***DO*** with that calculated `CMAttitude`. Assuming a user has the iPhone in their hand, begins a measurement and flexes their arm, so that their elbow collapses from extended (180º) to collapsed (say, 45º). Depending on how they are holding the device, it seems like I could get very, very different calculated attitudes.

In another scenario, say a user holds the iPhone in their hand palm-up. Then, without moving their arm (the phone stays "in place"), they rotate their hand palm-down. Clearly, that's something like a 180º rotation.

Now, in both of the above scenarios, I think I could figure out how to do the measurement if I can guarantee how the user is holding the device to start. For the elbow, I could have them hold the device "top up / screen left", which would mean that the yaw measurement would give me the answer I seek.

For the wrist rotation, if the user starts with the phone "screen up / top right", then I could isolate pitch as my measurement.

What I'd like to find is a more generic way to find a common angle of rotation between any two attitudes (or, from a single, calculated, "delta" attitude).

Am I even thinking of this correctly?

If you're going to respond with advanced math, please give me resources or simple explanations. I don't mind reading up on this topic, but some of the answers I've seen related to this on other questions are so dense that I don't even know where to start with them.

---

***EDIT***

I've been reading up on this more over the past few hours, and I have an idea, but wanted to run it by someone with more experience on this matter. I've also been running on-device experiments and experiencing gimbal lock at the edge of pitch's range and oddities at the edge of roll's range.

So, from what I can tell, a `CMAttitude` instance represents the iPhone's position in 3-dimensional space. It can be asked to represent itself in Euler angles (pitch, roll, yaw), or Quaternions (x, y, z, w).

If so, for my purposes, could I calculate the angle between 2 quaternions' vectors (x1, y1, z1) vs. (x2, y2, z3) and compare it to the difference between w1 and w2? If the angle of difference between the vectors is sufficiently small, then wouldn't the difference between the "w" rotations be what I seek? Does that make sense, or have I missed the essence of quaternions?